# ASP.NET MVC C# dynamic url depending on page variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If someone loads say three or four entries, when they search and they select entry two to edit, when they click the open button, how would I make it go to say `/entry/2` or if they opened entry three it would say `/entry/3` ?

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC so I'm really not sure what I am doing:

```
@model IEnumerable<Savvy_CRM_MVC.Models.RootObject>
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}

@foreach (var m in Model)
{
}

<table class="mui-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Case ID</th>
            <th>Forename</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Postcode</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var m in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@m.Caseid</td>
                <td>@m.Forename</td>
                <td>@m.Surname</td>
                <td>@m.Postcode</td>
                <td><button>Open Case</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When clicking the button, I want the url to change and it to load the data of that entry to the page in a format that will be decided later.

Comment: Create a link (using `@Html.ActionLink(...)` and pass the value of `Caseid` as a route parameter to your method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to change the button into a hyperlink:

```
@foreach (var m in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@m.Caseid</td>
                <td>@m.Forename</td>
                <td>@m.Surname</td>
                <td>@m.Postcode</td>
                <td><a href="/entry/"+@m.CaseId>Open Case</a></td>
            </tr>
        }
```

This will generate a GET request to the "entry/{id}" route.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah ok this works for redirecting but it redirects me to an error 404 page how do i get it to show the view i have a CaseController that has an index and i also have an index.cshtml but it doesnt show it

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Open Case", "Index", "Case", new { id = m.CaseId }, null)`